# Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)?

Tags: android, syntax, syntax-error

I'm trying to create a class called broadcastMensajes that extends BroadcastReceiver, I'm using the code provided here: http://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62&aaid=87

Eclipse underlines almost all the code, and says `"Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens"`.

`"Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)"` at the `if` inside the `try`

The code is ok, why is this happening?

This is the code:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;

public class broadcastMensajes extends BroadcastReceiver {


    AccionesExecuter Ejecutor = new AccionesExecuter();
    final SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
     
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        

        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
 
        try {
             
            if (bundle != null) {
                 
                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                 
                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                     
                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                     
                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                     
                } // end for loop
              } // bundle is null
 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" + e);
             
        }
    }    
}
```

Error log:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)    broadcastMensajes.java  /Actions/src/com/nahue/actions  line 27 Java Problem
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens broadcastMensajes.java  /Actions/src/com/nahue/actions  line 14 Java Problem
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens broadcastMensajes.java  /Actions/src/com/nahue/actions  line 15 Java Problem
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens broadcastMensajes.java  /Actions/src/com/nahue/actions  line 16 Java Problem
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens broadcastMensajes.java  /Actions/src/com/nahue/actions  line 20 Java Problem
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens broadcastMensajes.java  /Actions/src/com/nahue/actions  line 27 Java Problem
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens broadcastMensajes.java  /Actions/src/com/nahue/actions  line 29 Java Problem
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens broadcastMensajes.java  /Actions/src/com/nahue/actions  line 31 Java Problem
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens broadcastMensajes.java  /Actions/src/com/nahue/actions  line 31 Java Problem
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens broadcastMensajes.java  /Actions/src/com/nahue/actions  line 33 Java Problem
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens broadcastMensajes.java  /Actions/src/com/nahue/actions  line 34 Java Problem
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens broadcastMensajes.java  /Actions/src/com/nahue/actions  line 36 Java Problem
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens broadcastMensajes.java  /Actions/src/com/nahue/actions  line 37 Java Problem
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens broadcastMensajes.java  /Actions/src/com/nahue/actions  line 43 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement  broadcastMensajes.java  /Actions/src/com/nahue/actions  line 43 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block  broadcastMensajes.java  /Actions/src/com/nahue/actions  line 43 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody  broadcastMensajes.java  /Actions/src/com/nahue/actions  line 18 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody broadcastMensajes.java  /Actions/src/com/nahue/actions  line 18 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert "else Statement" to complete IfStatement   broadcastMensajes.java  /Actions/src/com/nahue/actions  line 43 Java Problem
```

Comment: your code is fine in my look, did you import log? `import android.util.Log;`

Comment: Added, it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add all supported imports like:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;

public class BroadcastMensajes extends BroadcastReceiver {
    AccionesExecuter Ejecutor = new AccionesExecuter();
    final SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {
            if (bundle != null) {
                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                } // end for loop
              } // bundle is null
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" + e);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: clean your project and re build it.

Comment: Your code works! What did you change? Thank you so much!

Comment: i removed spaces and format the text thats it, any how it is working fine cool :)